# Arithmetic Mean, Geometric Mean, Harmonic Mean and their relations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, means

If $a$ be the arithmetic mean between $b$ and $c$, $b$ be the geometric mean between $c$ and $a$ then prove that $c$ is the harmonic mean between $a$ and $b$. I expressed $a$ as $$a=\frac{(b+c)}{2}$$ $$b=\sqrt {ac}$$ . I solved the equations but I could not evaluate for $c$

Comment: What do you mean you solved if you cannot evaluate for $c$?

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner he tried to solve the equation(he tried to solve for c), but he could not.

Answer (score 5):

We know that $c=2a-b=b^2/a$ ($a$ and $c$ must have the same sign). We have to prove that 
$$
c=\frac{2}{(1/a+1/b)}=\frac{2ab}{a+b}
$$
So let's take the difference:
$$
2a-b-\frac{2ab}{a+b}=\frac{2a^2+2ab-ab-b^2-2ab}{a+b}=\frac{a(2a-b)-b^2}{a+b}
$$
Since $b^2=a(2a-b)$ this difference is zero.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** It is a rather well-known and beautiful fact, that the geometric mean of two numbers is also the geometric mean between the arithmetic and harmonic mean of those two numbers:

$\qquad\qquad\quad G=\sqrt{uv}\iff G=\sqrt{AH},~$ where $~A=\dfrac{u+v}2~$ and $~H=\dfrac{2uv}{u+v}$

Answer (score 2):

a is the arithmetic mean between b and c

```
       a = (b+c)/2 --------------(1)
```

‘b’ is the geometric mean between a and c

```
b = √ac  OR b^2= ac - - - - - - - - (2)
```

by Multiplying  eqn(1) by ‘b’ and replacing b2 by  eqn (2) in (1) we get,

ab = b ((b+c)/2)

ab =  (b2 +bc )/2

ab = (ac +bc )/2

ab = c(a+b) )/2

c = 2ab /(a+b)

hence c is the haromonic mean of a and b

Answer (score 0):

$$a=\frac{b+c}2\tag{AM}$$
$$b=\sqrt{ac}\tag{GM}$$

---

$$2a=b+c\tag{from AM,(1)}$$
$$2a=\sqrt{ac}+a\tag{from GM $b=\sqrt{ac}$}$$
$$a=\sqrt{ac}$$
$$\sqrt a=\sqrt c\implies a=c$$
Put $a=c$ in (1)
$$2a=b+a\implies b=a$$
So $a=b=c$, so c is the harmonic mean between a and b as:
$$\frac2c=\frac1a+\frac1b\tag{since $a=b=c$}$$

Comment: Error in calculation step 3.

Comment: I don't understand why $b+c=\pm\sqrt{ac}+a$. Where does the $\pm$ come from? And how come $c$ turns into $a$? And at the end, how can you drop $\sqrt{a}$ only on one side?

Comment: @bartgol firstly:$b^2=ac\implies b=\pm\sqrt{ac}$

Comment: @bartgol secondly:$a=c$

Comment: @bartgol thirdly:$a=\pm\sqrt{ac}\implies\sqrt{a}=\pm\sqrt{c}\implies a=c$

Comment: @Aditya $b=\sqrt{ac}$ by the definition. There is  no $+-$.

Comment: example $a=−1,c=−4,b=2$

Comment: When you talk about geometric mean, you don't allow negative numbers. If you do, you either get an imaginary mean, or a mean that lies outside the interval delimited by the two numbers. Either way, it doesn't fit our concept of "mean".

Comment: Also, you cannot assume $a=c$ to prove $a=c$! Your claim "secondly: $a=c$" is not supported by any argument...

Comment: @bartgol I have proved $a=b=c$

Comment: What I meant is that, in the second step, you replace $b$ with $\sqrt{ac}$, which is ok, but you also replace $c$ with $a$! How can you do that before proving that $a=c$?

Answer (score 0):

I think $a=b=c$ (and therefore all the means are the same).

Given the two equations, you get

$$
ac = b^2 = (2a-c)^2 = 4a^2 - 4ac +c^2
$$

Hence

$$
c^2 -5ac +4a^2 = 0
$$
which, solving for $c$, yields $c=a$ or $c=4a$. Now, since $b = 2a-c$, we can only have $b=a$ or $b=-2a$. Since $b$ cannot be negative (otherwise your second assumption would not hold), we get $b=a$ too.

Comment: Finally one has to arrive at $$c=\frac {2ab}{a+b}$$

Comment: If $a=b=c$, then $c=2ab/(a+b)$...

Comment: @bartgol example $a=-1,c=-4,b=2$. Your proof is wrong.

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner you don't allow negative numbers when you deal with geometric means.  Otherwise, you either get an imaginary mean (if one is positive) or a mean which is outside the interval. Either way, not fitting our idea of mean.

Comment: I agree generally, but your proof is wrong anyway. Check condition $b=-3a$.

Comment: If $b=-3a$, either $a$ is negative (and therefore the geometric mean is not meaningful) or $b$ is negative (which is impossible, cause $b=\sqrt{ac}$).

Comment: @bartgol $2a-4a=-2a$

Comment: Whoops! Edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Define
$$ d_1 := 2a-b-c,\quad d_2 := b^2-ac,\quad d_3 := (a+b)c-2ab $$
where $\,a,b,c\,$ are positive real numbers. Now

- $\,d_1=0\,$ is equivalent to $\,a\,$ being the arithmetic mean
  of $\,b\,$ and $\,c.$
- $\,d_2=0\,$ is equivalent to $\,b\,$ being the geometric mean
  of $\,c\,$ and $\,a.$
- $\,d_3=0\,$ is equivalent to $\,c\,$ being the harmonic mean
  of $\,a\,$ and $\,b.$

Verify the simple algebraic identity

$$ bd_1 + d_2 + d_3 = b(2a-b-c) + (b^2-ac) + ((a+b)c-2ab) = 0. $$

Given both $\,d_1 = 0\,$ and $\,d_2 = 0,\,$ then the identity
implies that $\,d_3 = 0.\,$ This proves the requested result

> If $a$ be the arithmetic mean between $b$ and $c$, $b$ be the geometric mean between $c$ and $a$ then prove that $c$ is the harmonic mean between $a$ and $b$.